# How to prompt keyboard on input space right after clicking on a tab bar button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

How can I click on one of the buttons on tab bar and have that interaction prompt a keyboard, ready to type into an input space like a search bar? I'm using swift. I can't find information on this anywhere.

Comment: You should checkout the tabbarcontrollerdelegate

Comment: Here is the URL : https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate

Comment: Have a look at tabbarcontroller ... didSelect: UIViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass `UITabBarController` and override `func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)`.

This allows you to react to a specific `item` being tapped.

Then you can send a `Notification` or call a function in your view controller that then calls `textField.becomeFirstResponder()`.

I have an app that reacts to `UITabBarItem` presses similar to this:

```
/// Enum cases must have the same name as the title of each tab bar item
enum MainTabBarItems: String {
  case tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4
}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
  guard let itemTitle = item.title?.lowercased() else { return }
  guard let tappedItemIndex = MainTabBarItems(rawValue: itemTitle)?.hashValue else { return }

  if tappedItemIndex == selectedIndex {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
      name: Constants.Notifications.tabBarItemTapped[tappedItemIndex],
      object: nil
    )
  }
}
```

`Constants.Notifications.tabBarItemTapped` is an array of strings, each corresponding to the tab bar items in the app.

Then in the view controller I would have:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tabBarItemWasTapped), name: Constants.Notifications.tabBarOneTapped, object: nil)
```

With target:

```
func tabBarItemWasTapped() {
  // react to the tab bar press
  textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the field to becomeFirstResponder in ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Hope this will help.
Wish you all the best.

Comment: This will only work if the text field is in a view controller tied to the tab button. If that tab button only activates the text field on a currently visible view controller, it won't work.